# when will dir(class_name) != dir(instance) in python

Tags: python

In Python, I checked whether dir() of a class name is equal to dir() of an object.

```
dir(str) == dir('hi')
dir(int) == dir(1234)
```

Both return True.

I was wondering whether there exists dir(class_name) != dir(instance).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, for one thing, when you add an attribute:

```
>>> class foo(object):
...     pass
... 
>>> x = foo()
>>> dir(x) == dir(foo)
True
>>> x.a = 3
>>> dir(x) == dir(foo)
False
```